# Show that f is differentiable at (0,0) using linearization and determine the derivative for the given function

Tags: calculus

*I asked this question before, but I would like to share my new thoughts and questions regarding this subject, as well as reflecting on the solution to this problem.*

Given the following function:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}(x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})&\text{ if }(x,y)\not =(0,0)\\0 &\text{ if }(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

we have to a) show that the function is differentiable at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and b) determine the detrivative.

**Part A**

For part a, we know that the first order partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$, so we can't use the following theorem: "If the partial derivatives $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist near $(a,b)$ and are continuous at $(a, b)$, then f is differentiable at $(a,b)$".

So we have to show in a different manner that this function is differentiable at (0,0), namely using the linearization of the function. We know that a differentiable function is one for which the linear approximation is a good approximation when $(x,y)$ is near $(a,b)$.

The solution to the problem is as follows:

The linearization at $(0,0)$ is given by
$$L(x,y) = f(0,0) + f_x(0,0)(x-0) + f_y(0,0)(y-0) = 0$$ (since $f_x(0,0) = f_y(0,0) = 0$).

We have to show that
$$\lim_{x,y\to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-L(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||} = 0$$

For $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, we have

$$\frac{f(x,y)-L(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||} = \frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

$$-(x^2 + y^2) \leq f(x,y) \leq x^2 + y^2$$
$$-\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Since
$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0$, we have

$$\lim_{x,y\to (0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-L(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||} = 0$$

I get why the limit is equal to 0 by using the Squeeze theorem, but I don't understand the first part:

*Why do we have to show that $\lim_{x,y\to (0,0)}       \frac{f(x,y)-L(x,y)}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||} = 0$ in the first place? I       don't completely understand what this equation means, and how this       equation shows that the function is differentiable at (0,0)?*

**Part B**
Now we are asked to determine the derivative. I still don't quite understand what the 'derivative' means in the context of functions of two variables. We only have partial derivatives in this context right?
According to the solution, the derivative of $f$ at $(x,y) = (0,0)$ is

$$\nabla f(0,0) = \; <f_x(0,0), f_y(0,0)> \; = \; <0,0>$$

*However, this is the gradient of the function evaluated at $(0,0)$ right? Or is the gradient equivalent to the derivative in the context of a function of two variables?*

Comment: How do you define “differentiable function”?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The problem simply asked me to show that the function is differentiable at (0,0), without specifying a 'specific definition'. Normally, a function is differentiable by the given theorem, but we can't use that theorem here since the partial derivatives are not continuous at (0,0), yet the function is still differentiable.

Comment: If you do not know what a differentiable function is, then you cannot solve the problem .

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking this as a test of my understanding, or because a differentiable function is ambiguous since you have to specify a specific definition. I did mention in my post the following:
"We know that a differentiable function is one for which the linear approximation is a good approximation when (x,y) is near (a,b)."

Comment: I have no intention of testing your knowledge. That final sentence makes no sense (what is *the* linear approximation?) and it is, at best, an idea of what a differentiable function is.

Comment: The thing is that I don't understand why you have to show that the given equation is true in order to show that the function is differentiable at that point, which might give you a clue how a differentiable function is defined, but the whole point is that I don't understand WHY you have to show it. I have seen the given equation in multiple questions (on Stackexchange as well), which I don't understand.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "WHY". As Josè was pointing out, that is the exact definition of being differentiable at $(0,0)$. So if the question asks you to show that $f$ satisfies property $P$, you take $f$ and try to show that satisfies property $P$. Nothing more. I think you are asking WHY your intuitive definition of "best linear approximation" coincides with the actual definition given by the equation. In this case, I suggest you reformualte your question to focus more on this aspect! (I am not considering the "WHY" should I care of analysis, which I have no answers to. I am into algebra.)